# How to Use Correlation Sets with multiple Receive Shapes in BizTalk Orchestration

Tags: properties, biztalk, correlation, biztalk-orchestrations

My scenario is:

There are four txt-files created in a source-folder at the same time. They should be mapped to four xml-files. Then one of the xml-files should be sent to a remote Web Service and, if it was received properly, a response containing a "replacement-id" is coming back. And if so, finally, the replacement-id is mapped into the other three xml-files before they are sent to the Web Service.

I'm trying to control all the flow in one single orchestration. In my BizTalk Server Project I have all the schemas and maps that is needed. Since there must be four Receive Shapes in the Orchestration I understand I must deal with Correlation sets. There is one (date) field that is common to all the input txt-files and have the same unique value in each file. I assumed that this field could be used in a Correlation Set. But how is that done?

I've found questions on similar cases on forums but not yet found any answer that gives me the right clue to this case.

I tried this:

•   promoted the common field in all the files (a Property Schema was created for me)

•   created a Correlation Type based on the Property Schema

•   created a Correlation Set based on the Correlation Type

•   in the first Receive Shape: set Initializing Correlation Sets = my Correlation Set

•   in the other Receive Shapes: set Following Correlation Sets = my Correlation Set

•   the first Receive Shape has also Active = true and the others = false

This don’t work however. On building the solution I get errors telling that my Correlation Set does not exist in the messages I use as input to the mappings. The “blocking stone” is that I don’t seem know how to use Correlation Sets the right way to solve a Multiple-Receive-Shape problem. (Hope that calling the Web Service and mapping the replacement-id won’t be a problem when I get that far.) Would be glad if someone could correct the list of steps or put me on the right road if I’m completely wrong.

Comment: As John's said below your question in Technet, do a search for BizTalk parallel convoy.  e.g. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35526.biztalk-demo-parallel-convoys.aspx   The trick is using a parallel shape and that all the receive shapes have the Initializing Correlation Sets